# Disable Centos 7 Firewalld

Tags: centos, centos7, firewalld

I have been having issues sending mail from my server. I am connecting to office365 on port 587 but it keeps looping back to my local smtp server running on 587. At first I figured it was DNS issue pointing to 127.0.0.1 so I changed to use the office365 ip, but was still getting my local smtp so I shutdown my local smtp to remove it from the issue but then got connection refused.

I eventually figured out it was the firewall doing dodgey stuff and disabled it, I can now netcat to the ip and port as root and get the office365 ehlo

```
[root@web ~]# ncat 40.101.6.90 587
220 VI1PR0801CA0052.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 13 Dec 2016 11:51:16 +0000
```

But from a non root user I get connection refused

```
[centos@web ~]$ ncat 40.101.6.90 587
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

I have also disabled selinux. I don't know whats going on when I disable my firewall it only seems to do it for root and firewall-cmd --state still shows the firewall as running.

```
[root@web ~]# systemctl stop firewalld
[root@web ~]# systemctl disable firewalld
[root@web ~]# firewall-cmd --state
running
[root@web ~]#
```

I also don't understand why its looping back ports like its got a messed up nat or something and then blocking outgoing ports by default, this thing is a mess. I miss iptables.

Comment: "I miss iptables" - me too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you did a good job of disabling the firewalld service. Try rebooting the server - it shouldn't say "running" then. If you can't reboot the server then firewalld is based on iptables. So you can use iptables commands like:

```
iptables -nvL
```

and

```
iptables -nvL -t nat
```

to see what rules may be left. The following are examples of how to flush out any of the rules:

```
iptables -F POSTROUTING -t nat
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F OUTPUT
```

Careful of the policy though. If it is set to DROP then flushing out the rules will deny all traffic.

Once you have either rebooted or cleared out any of the unwanted rules from iptables, you could just leave firewalld off and go back to using iptables!

Comment: Oh sweet thats fixed and got me back iptables! Thanks.

Comment: @WalkerCommunications You're welcome. Don't forget to also set policies for ip6tables if you need it.